# JSON.NET date with space in timezone offset

Tags: .net, json.net, timezone-offset

I have an odd issue with a VB.NET program (VS2012 / .NET framework 4) which uses JSON.NET (Newtonsoft) v4.0.8 to serialise objects. There are some dates amongst the properties of the class I'm serialising, and normally a date will be serialised to include a timezone offset of +0000 or +0100 which is what I would expect. However, on a customer's computer the plus is being serialised as a space, and then on being deserialised later (having been in a database, but in the same VB.NET program using the same JSON.NET DLL), the deserialise method throws an exception saying the string isn't in the correct format (and I can see it's when it's trying to parse a number at the heart of the JSON.NET DLL).

An example of a date I would see on my computer and on nearly all customers' computers is:

> "/Date(1455017231091+0000)/"

whereas for this one customer (and possibly some others, judging by the number of times I've seen the resultant exception) it comes out like this:

> "/Date(1455017231091 0000)/"

I'm not even sure how I can reliably deal with this (probably a regex which looks for the appropriate number of digits followed by a space and then four digits) but first of all I want to find out if this is something normal and whether I can stop it happening by using a setting on the date serialiser.

Note that since this has been in production I know that JSON.NET has switched by default to the ISO8601 date format, which I am considering using, but I would also need to convert all existing dates stored in the database first.

The code I am currently using to serialise looks like this:

`stringStoredInDatabase = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instanceOfT)`

and the code to deserialise looks like this:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(stringStoredInDatabase)`

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to see how this could be happening during serialization.  If you look at the [source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/4.0.8) for 4.0.8, [`JsonConvert.WriteDateTimeString()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/4.0.8/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L116) is called, which does `writer.Write((offset.Ticks >= 0L) ? "+" : "-");`  Is there any chance a custom converter deriving from [`DateTimeConverterBase`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/4.0.8/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DateTimeConverterBase.cs) is being used?

Comment: Hypothetically, if a custom converter were being used which formatted the time zone offset using [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) (which would be a bug, since serialization should **always** be culture-invariant) then, if the customer's computer override [`NumberFormatInfo.PositiveSign`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.positivesign.aspx) to be a space, you would get the bug you see.  But Json.NET is not doing that in its own code.

Comment: If you were using a newer version of Json.Net you could potentially fix the issue with a custom JsonConverter.  But 4.0.8 does not provide a way to turn off the automatic parsing of Microsoft format date strings.

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestions. I'm not changing anything from default settings at all, with no custom converters. It's difficult to find out more as I got this error via an error handler which calls home to tell me there's been an exception. I will start by upgrading JSON.NET to v10.0.3 and increase my options.

Comment: Right then. I haven't got a solution, but I have a workaround. I have upgraded to JSON.NET v10.0.3 and I have set all my serialisation to use the new default date handling settings (i.e. leave it to product ISO8601 date string), but I have also used global settings to make sure I get the timezone as UTC in all dates:

`Friend theJsonSerialiserSettings As New JsonSerializerSettings With {.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc}`

I can only ignore the past, unfortunately, and get customer to upgrade. I would recommend anyone doing date serialisation with JSON.NET avoid v<4.5.